# How to iterate through keys in a dict and match against key/val in another dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to build a program that will take either nested lists of [int,int] or key/value pairs and match against key/val of another dict and add the values from the second to an int variable initiated at 0.

```
from collections import Counter

shoe_sizes = [2,3,4,5,6,8,7,6,5,18]
shoe_collection = Counter(shoe_sizes)
customer_wants = [[6,55],[6,45], [6,55], [4,40], [18,60], [10, 50]]

income = 0
for i in customer_wants:
    if i in shoe_collection:
        income += dict[customer_wants[i][1]]
    print(income)
```

The keys in `shoe_collection` are shoe sizes and the values are how many are available.
What I'm trying to do here is to take each nested list in `customer_wants` and check if the first element (shoe size) is available in `shoe_collection`. If so, I want to add the second element of that nested list (the price) in `customer_wants` and add it to `income`.
Would it be easier to use two dicts rather instead of having `customer_wants` as nested lists? I tried comparing both list-dict and dict-dict but got TypeErrors that both weren't hashable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop with this one:

```
for size, price in customer_wants:
    if shoe_collection[size] > 0:
        shoe_collection[size] -= 1
        income += price
```

This works on the principle that, [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects return `0` for missing keys, as per the docs:

> Counter objects have a dictionary interface except that they return a zero count for missing items instead of raising a KeyError

So there is no need to check whether a key exists, we just need to check if that key has a positive value. If it does, then decrease the value by `1` and add price to the income.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can put it in this way,

```
shoe_sizes = [2,3,4,5,6,8,7,6,5,18]

customer_wants = [{'size':6,'value':55},{'size':6,'value':45}, {'size':6,'value':55}, {'size':4,'value':40}, {'size':18,'value':60}, {'size':10, 'value':50}]
income = 0
for i in customer_wants:
    if i['size'] in shoe_sizes:
       income+=i['value']
```

Comment: Hey shajahan, each value in shoe_sizes represents one shoe of that size. Once customer_wants[i]['size'] is matched with a value in shoe_sizes, that value would need to be removed for the list. Your solution causes income to be 255 rather than 200 because it doesn't account for only two 6s in shoe_sizes, while there are three dictionaries containing 'size': 6 in customer_wants.